# Literature about putative epigenetic state changes in mammal sequences after cloning steps in Escherichia coli

Tags: epigenetics, cloning, ecoli

I would like you to point me out some literature about putative epigenetic state changes in mouse/mammal sequences after cloning steps in *Escherichia coli*.

This are the last search details I used in NCBI PubMed:

> "epigenomics"[MeSH Terms] AND "cloning, molecular"[MeSH Terms] OR
>   "molecular cloning"[All Fields] AND "sequence"[All Fields] AND
>   ("escherichia coli"[All Fields] OR "e. coli"[All Fields])

Comment: Where do these epigenetic changes happen? while cloning a mammal DNA in E.coli?

Comment: I am interested in finding any record of epigenetic changes while cloning mammal DNA via _E. coli_ (so, the initial DNA would have its epigenetic state, the purified plasmidic DNA after the molecular cloning would have another, possibly different, epigenetic state). By the way, any paper suggesting conservation in the epigenetic state through the cloning steps is also welcome, as it would provide evidence of the lack of changes.

Comment: I think you can narrow it down to DNA-methylation since bacteria don't have histones.

Comment: This is mostly true, but in principle I would like to include any possible bookmarking event.

Answer (score 1):

*E.coli* strains that have *dam* or *dcm* methylases can methylate plasmid at adenines or cytosines respectively. See [here](https://www.neb.com/tools-and-resources/usage-guidelines/dam-and-dcm-methylases-of-e-coli) — It is a NEB web page but has links to the cited references.

DH5α has both the methylases- *dam<sup>+</sup> dcm<sup>+</sup>* , BL21 is *dam<sup>+</sup> dcm<sup>−</sup>* and ET12567 is *dam<sup>−</sup> dcm<sup>−</sup>*